# SKShapeNode collision detection in Sprite kit not detecting collision

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I am trying to achieve collision detection between a `SKShapeNode`(a circlular node) and `SKShapeNode`(a square node), just like the app "Snake VS Blocks".

Below is my code snippet of my node creations

## Snake Creation

```
 private func addSnake() {
        snake = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: Constants.snakeRadius)
        snake.fillColor = Constants.snakeColor
        let snakeXPosition = (Helper.getScreenWidth() / 2.0) - Constants.snakeRadius
        snake.position = CGPoint(x: snakeXPosition, y: size.height * 0.3)
        snake.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: snake.frame.size)
        snake.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        snake.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.snake
        snake.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.block
        snake.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.none
        snake.name = "Snake"
        addChild(snake)
    }
```

## Block Creation

```
func addBlocks() {
    for index in 0...(blockCount-1) {
       let hasBlock = getRandomBool()
        if hasBlock {
            let block = getBlock(for: index)
            block.fillColor = .red
            addChild(block)
            let actionMove = getBlockMoveAction(for: block, atIndex: index)
            let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            block.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
        }
    }
}

func getBlockMoveAction(for block: SKShapeNode, atIndex: Int) -> SKAction {
    return SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:  CGFloat(atIndex) * width, y: -block.frame.size.height),
                  duration: TimeInterval(blockMovementDuration))
}

func getBlock(for index: Int) -> SKShapeNode {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: width)
    let block = SKShapeNode(rect: rect, cornerRadius: Constants.blockCornerRadius)
    block.name = "Block"
    block.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index) * width, y: (Helper.getScreenHeight() + width))
    block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: block.frame.size)
    block.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    block.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.block
    block.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.snake
    block.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.none
    return block
}

func getRandomBool() -> Bool {
    return arc4random_uniform(2) == 0
}
```

Below is the image of the outcome of above code:

[image: Screenshot of the app]

My first problem is, I don't know why, but when I enabled, skview to show physics,
`view.showsPhysics = true`

i found out my view is not in correct frame

Secondly, I have confirmed to  contact delegate as well

```
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

But my

```
didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)
```

is not getting triggered

## collision detection code:

```
extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA //snake
        secondBody = contact.bodyB //block
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB //block
        secondBody = contact.bodyA //snake
    }
    
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.snake != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.block != 0)) {
        if let snake = firstBody.node as? SKShapeNode,
            let block = secondBody.node as? SKShapeNode {
            snakeDidCollideWithBlock(snake: snake, block: block)
        }
    }
}

func snakeDidCollideWithBlock(snake: SKShapeNode, block: SKShapeNode) {
    print("Hit")
    block.removeFromParent()
    
}

}
```

I went through other questions in stackoverflow searching for similar problem, but didnt find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Either one or both "isDynamic" should be true. Otherwise, they will behave like a wall and never participate in a physical simulation.

Comment: that was quick.. I forgot I had both bodies set dynamic false. Can you tell me why my block's frame is in some offset than what it should be as you can see in the image above.

Comment: Still physics body's frame and the node's frame has different anchor points.  One is at the center of nodes(0.5,0.5) and the other is at one vertex(0,0).  If physics body is in simulated, physics world engine will correct its position to match the node and you would not notice the difference.